# Laptop receiving garbage serial information

Tags: serial-port

When reading continuous serial information to Putty, Docklight or Hyperterminal, the information is unrecognizable on my laptop. If tested on other laptops, the information is legible and accurate. Is there possibly a blanket setting that I could have incorrect for receiving that information?.

Comment: There are few parameters, such as baud, parity, stop bits, etc. However, this doesn't seem to be a programming question. Consider migrating to [su].

Comment: Here's the Wikipedia settings section: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serial_port#Settings